# Returning to a menu after an external application is done or cancelled

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, exit

I am writing up an interface that references several external Utilities and Anti Virus applications. In this case, I have one menu that has options for things like Malwarebytes, CCleaner, Windirstat, etc.

My issue is that if you cancel the external program, I get an error and the whole interface goes down with the debug error "The operation was canceled by the user".

What I need is for the main interface to come back up so that I can select another tool if I cancel or finish.

Here is the main part of my code thus far. Keep in mind that I've been programming in c# for all of 3 days now:

```
private void ccleanerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set p as new process
    Process p = new Process();
    //select the process file name
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "ccsetup.exe";
    //Start things up
    p.Start();          
}
```

When I'm debugging (in Visual Studio C# 2010 Express), the "p.Start();" is what gets highlighted. As you can tell, it's  simple process call. I've been all over Google, this forum and others, but I don't seem to be asking the right questions.

Comment: Here is an msdn link that might help: support.microsoft.com/kb/305369.

Comment: Can you please include the full error message that you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to close processes is by using [CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) if you want to close your main GUI window and all child windows or [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) if you're looking to close a child window of your GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but no joy.

Tergiver – The system finds the file just fine (I imported the .exe into Visual Studios). It starts up just fine also, but if I cancel the external program, the whole thing goes down.
Doctor – I tried that (both of them), but it still does not process past the p.Start(); line.

Comment: @Hallofo so why don't you catch that exception and swallow it?

Comment: Tergiver makes a good point. Here's a link on exception handling in C# in case you're not familiar with it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Psychic debugger enabled . . .

Process.Start is throwing a Win32Exception with the Message, "The system cannot find the file specified"

Solution: Set StartInfo.Filename to the full path of the file you want to execute.